# How do I can access variables from match-case expression outside of the scope?

Tags: python, variables, flask, scope

I have an app running on Flask and inside of endpoint function I have variables named: layer_1, layer_2.

```
@app.route("/", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def index():
    current_map = folium.Map(location=(0.0, 0.0))

    layer_1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Name 1").add_to(current_map)
    layer_2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Name 2").add_to(current_map)

return render_template("index.html", maps=current_map._repr_html_())
```

And I have a function outside of the index scope:

```
def add_marker(location, color: str, popup: str, tooltip: str):
    """Add a marker to the map."""
    match color:
        case "red":
            layer = layer_1  # Unresolved reference 'layer_1' 
        case "yellow":
            layer = layer_2  # Unresolved reference 'layer_2' 

    try:
        folium.CircleMarker(
            location=location,
            popup=popup,
            tooltip=tooltip,
            radius=7,
            fill_color=color,
            color="gray",
            fill_opacity=0.6,
        ).add_to(layer)
```

How do I can access layer_1 and layer_2 vars from match-case expression?

Comment: Just pass them as arguments to your `add_marker` function

Comment: If you want to persist them tho, you might wanna store layers data somewhere, maybe in Redis, maybe in some singleton class, maybe in some persistent dictionary, maybe in some file.